# Log messages on Rsyslog server do not strictly follow RFC-5424 format

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to log messages into a linux server which has Rsyslog installed on it

Here is one of the sample message

**Feb 20 11:31:46 localhost -** <46>1 2020-02-20T11:31:46+00:00 localhost   [meta sequenceId="3"] -- MARK --#012

The part in **bold** is not part of RFC-5424 format

The Rsyslog agent seems to be adding this. How do I get rid of this ? And read only the remaining part

Answer (score 0):

i too find rsyslog it confusing. I want to configure rsyslog to strictly for rfc5424, but cant seem to find how.

Also when i send a syslog to it over TCP, i dont see  part at all, the messages logged simply start with timestamp.